# How to find the correlation coefficient between two technologies when those are sub correlated?

Tags: correlation

Suppose I have two power generating technologies, Coal and Oil, of which the generating cost components(total generating cost = Capital cost+Fuel cost+Variable O&M cost+Fixed O&M cost) are correlated in the following manner:

```
                                         Oil
                      Fuel           Variable O&M             Fixed O&M
           Fuel       0.48              0                       0
Coal    Var O&M       0                 0.7                     0.1
      Fixed O&M       0                 0.1                     0.7
```

Suppose Technology A is COAL and Technology B is OIL. How do I find the correlation between the total costs of the two technologies, that is COAL and OIL (one correlation coefficient) when three categories of costs are already correlated as given above?
I have the weights of cost components of each total technology cost and the standard deviation of each cost component of the two technologies as well.

Comment: How do you obtain diagonal values that are not identically $1$? Is this perhaps a *covariance* matrix rather than a correlation matrix?

Comment: It says cross-correlation matrix, but I'm not too sure. Can you kindly refer the page 37 of this file --> http://www.awerbuch.com/shimonpages/shimondocs/iea-portfolio.pdf ,maybe you'll get a clear idea than me explaining since my English is not good. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you: I had misunderstood this table. It shows "assumed cross-correlations for the cost streams of existing generation assets."  In order for your question to be answerable, you will also need to assume correlations among the different cost streams (within each technology).

Comment: Lets assume that there is no correlations among different cost streams within the same technology.

Comment: Mods, can you please forward this to someone who can answer this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me update your table to reduce confusion by making different variable names unique:

```
                                         Oil
                     Fuel.O          VarO&M.O               FixedO&M.O
           Fuel.C     0.48              0                       0
Coal     VarO&M.C     0                 0.7                     0.1
       FixedO&M.C     0                 0.1                     0.7
```

You have given 9 entries of a correlation matrix, but there should be a further 6 subdiagonal elements, being the correlations within Coal and within Oil.

For further simplicity:

$C_f$ Fuel.C
$C_v$ VarO&M.C
$C_x$ FixedO&M.C
$O_f$ Fuel.O
$O_v$ VarO&M.O
$O_x$ FixedO&M.O

$C = C_f + C_v + C_x$

$O = O_f + O_v + O_x$

$$\operatorname{Cov}(C,O) = \operatorname{Cov}(C_f + C_v + C_x,O_f + O_v + O_x)$$

$$= σ_{C_f}⋅σ_{O_f}⋅0.48+ σ_{C_v} ⋅σ_{O_v}⋅0.7+ σ_{C_x}⋅σ_{O_x}⋅0.7\\
+ σ_{C_v}⋅σ_{O_x}⋅0.1+ σ_{C_x}⋅σ_{O_v}⋅0.1$$

Using the "no correlation within" specified in comments:

$σ_C= \sqrt{σ_{C_f}^2+ σ_{C_v}^2+ σ_{C_x}^2}$
$σ_O = \sqrt{σ_{O_f}^2+ σ_{O_v}^2+ σ_{O_x}^2}$

$\text{Corr}(C,O)= \text{Cov}(C,O)/ (σ_C⋅σ_O)$

From there, it's impossible to simplify further, but the question states that the remaining quantities $σ_{C_f}, ..., σ_{O_v}$ are all known so it's a simply matter of substitution from here.

Comment: I think those sub-diagonal elements are zero. "Lets assume that there is no correlations among different cost streams within the same technology. – Kanch Dec 9 '12 at 18:15" and can you kindly explain how to calculate σC and σO if those elements are zero. Thank you.

Comment: @Ryan You're right; I didn't see that important information buried in comments. (This is why it's important for posters who update important information in comments to edit it back into the question.). I have edited my answer (and corrected an error in what I had) - given the additional information that's unspecified but stated by the original poster to be known, this should now be a solved problem. (Are you the original poster under a new account?)

Comment: @Ryan I just had one final read through and noticed an error - where I had $σ_O^2 = \sqrt{}...$ that should have been $σ_O  = \sqrt{}...$ (this was caused by initially giving the formulas in terms of the variances and then editing to give in terms of s.d.s). I hope that change doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: @Glen_b , When we find the Corr(C,O) as stated above, can't it give an answer greater than 1 which is not acceptable for a Correlation coefficient? (In case all S.d.s values are smaller than one say 0.1)

Comment: The only way it's possible to get it to give a correlation greater than one is if there's an error. Can you give some numbers where you think it leads to a correlation greater than 1?

Comment: @Glen_b, I did not use the above matrix for my calculation and calculated σC in a different way (I also considered the respective fractional weights of each cost component when calculating σC as suggested by the authors of the pdf file of which the link is given above) Maybe I have to do the same to the correlation matrix as well I wonder? (I'm sorry but I find it difficult to post the correlation matrix in a comment due to the simple formatting )

Comment: @Kanch It sounds like you didn't do the same calculation as above, but I don't clearly get what you did do. This makes it hard for me to see where the problem lies or how to resolve it. Indeed it sounds like a new question, one involving weights.